# What is the explicit formula for a boundary operator from $C_p(K)$ to $C_{p-1}(K))$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Suppose $K$ be a simplicial complex and denote the group of $p-\text{chains}$ from the set of oriented $p-\text{simplices}$ of $K$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ by $C_p(K)$, $p>0$. Let the set of oriented $p-\text{simplices}$ of $K$ be denoted by $S$.

If $\sigma$ is an oriented simplex, then the elementary chain $c$ corresponding to $\sigma$ is a function of the form $c:S\to \mathbb{Z}$ such that \begin{equation}c(\sigma)=0, c(-\sigma)=0  \text{ and } c(\tau)=0 \text{ for all other oriented simplices } \tau\end{equation}

We know that $C_p(K)$ is a free abelian group whose basis elements are elementary chains. We can denote the elementary chain corresponding to $\sigma$ by $c_\sigma$ and Munkres writes $c=\sum n_i\sigma_i$ by abuse of notation, using $\sigma_i$ to mean $c_{\sigma_i}$.

> We wish to draw a homomorphism from $C_p(K)$ to $C_{p-1}(K)$. The author writes down the map $\partial_p$ where $\partial_p$ takes a **p-simplex** $\sigma$ (instead of a $p-\text{chain}$), written $[v_0,\dots,v_p]$ to a $p-1$-simplex $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{p}(-1)^i[v_0,\dots,\hat{v_i},\dots,v_p]$ where a hat over vertex $v_i$ denotes that we consider the simplex generated by $v_0,\dots, v_p$ minus $v_i$.

Clearly, there is abuse of notation again. However, I am unable to pin down the map $\partial_p$ explicitly. There is, of course, a one-to-one correspondence of each $\sigma$ with $c_{\sigma}$. So, should $\partial_p(c_{[v_0,\dots,v_p]})$ equal $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{p}(-1)^ic_{[v_0,\dots,\hat{v_i},\dots,v_p]}?$

thanks!

Comment: The only difference between what you wrote and what the author wrote is the $c$, which makes formulas clumsy, and that's why the author doesn't use it.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, so my guess is correct? I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: You don't need to guess, the author is explicitly saying what the boundary map is. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.